# Calculate the total sum of points that cost to level up a character

Tags: java, calculator, javafx, role-playing-game

I'm learning JavaFX and how to make good code in general. I created a little aplication that let you calculate how many points cost to level up a character stats. But I noticed that I usually repeteat a good amount of code. Let's see what you guys think.

**Here's the Main.class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Calculadora de grajeas");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Here's the fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #364A5A;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: #4E6B81;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <GridPane prefHeight="295.0" prefWidth="290.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="NEVER" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="10.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="68.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="25.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="10.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Label text="Impacto físico" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <Label text="Defensa física" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Impacto mágico" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="if_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="df_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="im_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="if_a" focusColor="WHITE" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="80.0" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="df_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="im_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="dm_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="dm_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="in_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="r_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="hm_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="v_b" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="in_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="r_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="hm_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                  <JFXTextField fx:id="v_a" focusColor="WHITE" unFocusColor="#2abbe8" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
                  <Label text="Defensa mágica" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="Iniciativa" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                  <Label text="Resistencia" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                  <Label text="Habilidad mágica" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
                  <Label text="Vitalidad" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="15.0" right="15.0" />
               </padding>
            </GridPane>
            <JFXButton layoutX="234.0" layoutY="351.0" onAction="#calcularGrajeas" text="Calcular" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="400.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <JFXTextArea fx:id="outputText" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**And here's the Controller.class**

```
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextArea;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;


public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private JFXTextArea outputText;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField if_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField if_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField df_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField df_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField im_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField im_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField dm_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField dm_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField in_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField in_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField r_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField r_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField hm_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField hm_a;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField v_b;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField v_a;


    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void calcularGrajeas() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int total_points = 0;


        if (!(if_b.getText().isEmpty() || if_a.getText().isEmpty())) {
            int before = Integer.valueOf(if_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(if_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 30;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 30 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Strenght: %d\n", points));
        }

        if (!(df_b.getText().isEmpty() || df_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(dm_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(df_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 30;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 30 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Defense: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(im_b.getText().isEmpty() || im_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(im_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(im_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 50;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 50 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(dm_b.getText().isEmpty() || dm_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(dm_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(dm_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 50;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 50 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic Defense: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(in_b.getText().isEmpty() || in_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(in_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(in_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 50;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 50 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Iniciative: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(r_b.getText().isEmpty() || r_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(r_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(r_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 40;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 40 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Resistence: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(hm_b.getText().isEmpty() || hm_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(hm_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(hm_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 50;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 50 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic ability: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(v_b.getText().isEmpty() || v_a.getText().isEmpty())){

            int before = Integer.valueOf(v_b.getText());
            int after = Integer.valueOf(v_a.getText());
            int points = 0;


            for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
                if( i == 0){
                    points = points + 10;
                }else {
                    points = points+ 10 * i;
                }
            }

            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Vitality: %d\n",points));
        }

        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Total points: %d", total_points));
        outputText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

    }
}
```

Any tips about the code, formatting, what type of comments would be good to put, etc would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

## Explicitly instantiate the controller

You use implicit instantiation of the controller class by adding the attribute `fx:controller="sample.Controller"` to your FXML.

This has the disadvantage that the controller class must have a default constructor and any dependencies (like provided business logic (e.g. database access) or the *data model* (in reference to the `M` from the `MVVC` pattern that JavaFX incorporates)) have to be accesses in a *static* way either by invoking the `new` operator or via the *Singelton Pattern*. That makes your code hard to reuse and therefore hard to be unittested.

You should instead instantiate the controller instance explicitly in the class `Main`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    sample.Controller myController = new sample.Controller(/*pass dependencies here*/)
    // maybe some more configuration on myController 
    fxmlLoader.setController(myController);
    Parent root = flmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    // alternatively the controller could know its FXML file:
    Parent root = flmlLoader.load(myController.getFxmlFileAsResource()));
    // ...
```

## Enforce *separation of concerns* and *same level of abstraction*

Your controller class contains some calculation. 
But the (main) responsibility of a controller class is to organize the binding between the *data model* and the *view model* (the controllers properties annotated with `@FXML`) and triggering the business logic.
Any business related calculation should be done bye some other class having that responsibility only.

The *same level of abstraction* principle requires that a class should either delegate calls to other classes **or** do (primitive) calculations. 
Therefore you should move the calculations done in `calcularGrajeas()` to a method in another class which you call in your method `calcularGrajeas()`.

This suggestions might look like overkill for such a small project. 
But I believe  one should start to get used to the right concepts as soon as possible...

Comment: Okay, I instantiated the controller in the Main class, and I will use the controller only to organize the view. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: the more important point to me is: *Did you understand why?*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with JavaFX so I'll focus on things not related to it.

One thing that I would not recommend is to mix two languages when naming function (or anything really) in your language. You name every variable in English and then you use `calcularGrajeas` which is Spanish I guess? That's not really a good habit (I used to do the same, and it lead to confusion, and is harder to read for other people).

Still about naming, you have a lot of variables `if_b`, `if_a`, `df_b` .etc.
It's really unclear what they stand for. My guess is `_b` and `_a` stand for `before` and `after`? You should use longer names, to help with clarity. (edit: as suggested by @TimothyTruckles, the link to the Java naming convention is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html))

And then `calcularGrajeas` is very long, repeating a lot of code. One way to refactor it is as follow:

Define a function to calculate the points for one attribute (here I use `JFXTextField` as arguments, but you could use `int` with little modifications )

```
int calculatePointsAttribute(JFXTextField attribute_before, JFXTextField attribute_after)
{
    int points = 0;

    int before = Integer.valueOf(attribute_before.getText());
    int after = Integer.valueOf(attribute_after.getText());


    for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
        if( i == 0){
            points = points + 30;
        }else {
            points = points+ 30 * i;
        }
    }

    return points;
}
```

And then use it in your `calcularGrajeas` function:

```
private void calcularGrajeas() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int total_points = 0;
        int points = 0;


        if (!(if_b.getText().isEmpty() || if_a.getText().isEmpty())) {
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(if_b, if_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Strenght: %d\n", points));
        }

        if (!(df_b.getText().isEmpty() || df_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(df_b, df_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Defense: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(im_b.getText().isEmpty() || im_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(im_b, im_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(dm_b.getText().isEmpty() || dm_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(dm_b, dm_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic Defense: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(in_b.getText().isEmpty() || in_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(in_b, in_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Iniciative: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(r_b.getText().isEmpty() || r_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(r_b, r_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Resistence: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(hm_b.getText().isEmpty() || hm_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(hm_b, hm_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic ability: %d\n",points));
        }

        if (!(v_b.getText().isEmpty() || v_a.getText().isEmpty())){
            points = calculatePointsAttribute(v_b, v_a);
            total_points += points;
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("Vitality: %d\n",points));
        }

        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Total points: %d", total_points));
        outputText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

}
```

EDIT:

One other change you could consider if changing the logic a little bit isnt too much a problem is to define:

```
int calculatePointsAttribute(JFXTextField attribute_before, JFXTextField attribute_after)
{
    int points = 0;

    if (!(v_b.getText().isEmpty() || v_a.getText().isEmpty())){
        int before = Integer.valueOf(attribute_before.getText());
        int after = Integer.valueOf(attribute_after.getText());


        for (int i = before; i < after; i++) {
            if( i == 0){
                points = points + 30;
            }else {
                points = points+ 30 * i;
            }
        }
    }

        return points;
    }
```

Then `calcularGrajeas` become:

```
private void calcularGrajeas() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int total_points = 0;
        int points = 0;

        points = calculatePointsAttribute(if_b, if_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Strenght: %d\n", points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(df_b, df_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Defense: %d\n",points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(im_b, im_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic: %d\n",points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(dm_b, dm_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic Defense: %d\n",points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(in_b, in_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Iniciative: %d\n",points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(r_b, r_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Resistence: %d\n",points));

        points = calculatePointsAttribute(hm_b, hm_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Magic ability: %d\n",points));


        points = calculatePointsAttribute(v_b, v_a);
        total_points += points;
        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Vitality: %d\n",points));


        stringBuilder.append(String.format("Total points: %d", total_points));
        outputText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

}
```

And then you can also put all :

```
points = calculatePointsAttribute(X, X);
total_points += points;
stringBuilder.append(String.format("X: %d\n",points));
```

into a loop and your good to go!

Nice project!

Comment: I really have to stop mixing languages,  thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, It's an habit that is hard to lose, but it pay off eventually.

Comment: @JulienRousé would you mind to add the Link to the Java Naming Conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html ?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle good idea, I'll add it